# Why a function to customise ttk.Style() not work?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I can't figure out the cause of why function `customise_ttk_widgets_style(ss)` is causing the `ttk.Button` and `ttk.Labels` to not appear correctly. Commenting out line `# s = customise_ttk_style(s)` avoids the wrong widget appearances but I don't understand why this is so. Can you explain the cause and remedy of the issue? Thanks.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


BG = '#3b3b39'
FG = 'white'
DFONT = ('URW Gothic L', '10', 'Normal')


def customise_ttk_widgets_style(ss):
    # All Widgets
    ss.configure(".", font=DFONT, background=BG, foreground=FG, cap=tk.ROUND,
                 join=tk.ROUND)
    
    # main ttk.Frame
    ss.configure('Main.TFrame', background='pink')  # For debugging

    # Default ttk.Button
    ss.configure('TButton', padding=5, relief=tk.FLAT)
    ss.map('TButton',
           foreground=[("disabled", 'grey'), ('pressed', 'red'),
                       ('active', 'yellow')],
           background=[('disabled', '#646a67'), ('pressed', '!focus', BG),
                       ('active', '#535553')],
           relief=[('pressed', 'sunken'), ('!pressed', 'raised')],
           )
    return ss


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root['background'] = BG
    s = ttk.Style()
    s = customise_ttk_widgets_style(s)  # This function is causing problem
    button = ttk.Button(root, text="ttk.Button (!disabled)")
    dbutton = ttk.Button(root, text="ttk.Button (disabled)")
    dbutton.state(['!disabled', 'disabled'])
    label = ttk.Label(root, text="ttk.Label (!disabled)")
    dlabel = ttk.Label(root, text="ttk.Label (disabled)")
    dlabel.state(['!disabled', 'disabled'])
    button.grid(row=0, column=0)
    dbutton.grid(row=0, column=1)
    label.grid(row=1, column=0)
    dlabel.grid(row=1, column=1)
    root.mainloop()
```

Correct appearance:

[image: correct]

Wrong appearance:
[image: Wrong1] [image: wrong2]

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out the issue. The definition of `DFONT` was wrong. It ought to be defined as:

```
from tkinter import font
DFONT = font.Font(family='URW Gothic L', size=10, weight='bold')
```

But this definition can't be a global variable as `tk.Tk()` needs to be first defined. If `DFONT` is to be a global variable, it ought to be defined as a `dict()` object, i.e.

```
DFONT = dict(family='URW Gothic L', size=10, weight='bold')
```

Thereafter, in the `customise_ttk_widgets_style()` function, instead of

```
ss.configure(".", font=DFONT, background=BG, foreground=FG,
                 cap=tk.ROUND, join=tk.ROUND)
```

the correct syntax is:

```
ss.configure(".", font=font.Font(**DFONT), background=BG, foreground=FG,
                 cap=tk.ROUND, join=tk.ROUND)
```

The corrected script:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter import font


BG = '#3b3b39'
FG = 'white'
DFONT = dict(family='URW Gothic L', size=10, weight='bold')


def customise_ttk_widgets_style(ss):
    # All Widgets
    ss.configure(".", font=font.Font(**DFONT), background=BG, foreground=FG,
                 cap=tk.ROUND, join=tk.ROUND)
    # main ttk.Frame
    ss.configure('Main.TFrame', background='pink')  # For debugging

    # Default ttk.Button
    ss.configure('TButton', padding=5, relief=tk.FLAT)
    ss.map('TButton',
           foreground=[("disabled", 'grey'), ('pressed', 'red'),
                       ('active', 'yellow')],
           background=[('disabled', '#646a67'), ('pressed', '!focus', BG),
                       ('active', '#535553')],
           relief=[('pressed', 'sunken'), ('!pressed', 'raised')],
           )
    return ss


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root['background'] = BG
    s = ttk.Style()
    s = customise_ttk_widgets_style(s)
    button = ttk.Button(root, text="ttk.Button (!disabled)")
    dbutton = ttk.Button(root, text="ttk.Button (disabled)")
    dbutton.state(['!disabled', 'disabled'])
    label = ttk.Label(root, text="ttk.Label (!disabled)")
    dlabel = ttk.Label(root, text="ttk.Label (disabled)")
    dlabel.state(['!disabled', 'disabled'])
    button.grid(row=0, column=0)
    dbutton.grid(row=0, column=1)
    label.grid(row=1, column=0)
    dlabel.grid(row=1, column=1)
    root.mainloop()
```